# Condition if a String is empty

Tags: java, validation

I'm trying out a code that try's to sum 3 grades, (3 textboxes) and when you click the "Calculate" button , the 3 values get summed and get divided in 3, (1 avarage grade textbox)

My error comes when i'm validating if the 2nd and 3th textboxes are empty, it should only take the 1st textbox and make avarage grade out of it.

```
int p1,p2,p3,promedio; 

    p1=Integer.parseInt(par1.getText()); //getting the grade1 textbox info and parsing to int
    p2=Integer.parseInt(par2.getText()); //same , grade2
    p3=Integer.parseInt(par3.getText()); //same, grade3
    promedio=((p1+p2+p3)/3); //summing and dividing to 3
    String pp = String.valueOf(promedio); //parsing avarage grade to string
    pro.setText(pp); //printing the avarage grade to his respective textbox

    String pp1 = String.valueOf(p1); //parsing the 3 grades to strings, to i can validate later
    String pp2 = String.valueOf(p2);
    String pp3 = String.valueOf(p3);

    if(pp2.isEmpty() && pp3.isEmpty()){ //if grade 2 and 3 are empty
        pp = pp1; //avarage grade = p1 (grade 1)
        pro.setText(pp); //printing avarage grade
    }
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What error ??????

Comment: Which of these 3 variables are you trying to sum? (Also, I don't see any textboxes being used in this code sample here).

Comment: Side note: Why `promedio` is `int` and not `double`? Shouldn't it contain the average?

Comment: Well your if statements don't handle all of the cases. Say you have an entry in 2 but not in 3, the code doesn't know what to do in that case. Also what if you have an entry in 3 but not in 2, the code doesn't say what to do in that case either.

Comment: You're doing it backwards.  pp1/2/3 will never be empty, since p1/p2/p3 will always have values (if you get that far).  You need to check the getText results for empty.

Comment: You know, maybe you should post what exception you're getting, and identify what line that corresponds to.  If you've got empty string values coming in, you never get beyond the initial parseInt calls.

Answer (score 3):

if `par2.getText(),par3.getText()` are empty, then `Integer.parseInt(par1.getText());` will throw `NumberFormatException`

So you need to make sure that they are not empty and are valid numbers before converting it to int

Comment: *My error comes when i'm validating if the 2nd and 3th textboxes are empty*, that is probably `if(pp2.isEmpty() && pp3.isEmpty())` !!!

Comment: Mr @NoobUnChained It just needs presence of mind.. Because Possible that he'll get error when they are empty. above line won't throw any error AFAIK, because it was a string and he is check for empty

Comment: Sir @Pragnani ,If at all the textboxes are empty , I presume the execution won't reach till `if()` ;) And that's where the Op says he is getting "error" ..

Comment: @NoobUnChained yes you are right and that what I have mentioned in the Answer. He'll get `NumberFormatException` in the middle. He might be thinking that it was because of if condition... Don't call me sir friend.

Comment: @NoobUnChained - There's no way you could get to the isEmpty calls without pp2 and pp3 having been set by the earlier valueOf calls.  And the valueOf calls can never legally be reached unless the corresponding p values are set.  The strings will always be at least "0".

Comment: @Hot Licks, the point where the OP gets an error is `if()` statement as mentioned by him . That amazes me , may be he has not posted the entire code , may be he has skipped lines in between !

Comment: @NoobUnChained - Clearly the OP either hasn't posted the real code or has no idea how to read an exception message (likely both).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
p3=Integer.parseInt("0" + par3.getText());
```

It will only work for non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the order, and change the logic a little bit:

```
    String pp1 = par1.getText();
           pp2=...
           pp3=...

    int num = 3;
    if ( pp3.isEmpty() ) --num;
    if ( pp2.isEmpty() ) --num;
    // Add some logic for the case that pp1 is empty 

    p1 = ...
    p2 = .......
    promedio = ( p1 + p2 + p3 ) / num;

    pro.setText( String.valueOf( promedio ) );
```

In your code, you do things twice, like converting Strings to int, then back to String for validation later. So I changed this a little bit to show a shorter way (I didn't check my code, though, so maybe you still have to improve it :-)